# Why doesn't ng-hide/show work if expression is a scope variable modified on broadcast event

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have the following code:

script.js:

```
var app = angular.module('TestApp',[]);
app.factory('testfactory', function($rootScope, $window){
  var factory = {};
  factory.auth = function() {
    //This is only to make call to auth() async. 
    //Actual code is using google-api call.
    setTimeout(auth, 2000);             
  }
  $window.auth = function(){

      $rootScope.$broadcast('loggedin');  

  }
  return factory;
});
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, testfactory) {
  $scope.status = {
    loggedIn: false
  }
  $scope.test = testfactory;
  $scope.$on('loggedin', function(){
    $scope.status.loggedIn = true;
    alert('loggedIn');
  });
});
```

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  </head>

  <body ng-app="TestApp">
    <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
      <button ng-click="test.auth()" ng-hide="status.loggedIn">Auth</button>
    </div>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.2.19" data-semver="1.2.19" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.19/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>

</html>
```

This should hide the button "Auth" on clicking, however it does not. It works only when its clicked the second time. What's happening here? I'm modifying the scope variable inside angular's broadcasted event, so binding should work. What am I missing here?

**Edit:** I know wrapping the code within $scope.$apply works, but my question is why isn't it happening automatically, since I'm not modifying the variable from outside the scope.

Here's a plunker for this code - http://plnkr.co/edit/Ov568VDWCKarFHQjgbvG

**Answer:** This discussion on [google groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/angular/H6lEKY1F7u0) says $broadcast doesn't trigger auto-apply. So, if $broadcast is called from outside of angular-world, $apply must be applied manually.

Comment: Angular does a dirty check to evaluate all the watchers and update the view. It triggers this digest when angular knows about the code that's executing (within the angular context). If angular doesn't know about the code, it can't trigger a digest cycle. $apply is the solution to your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because Angular use $digest ([documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope), [and why/where to use](http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-angulars-apply-digest/)) to keep the binding between the $scope and the interface. Try to force the $digest:

```
$scope.$on('loggedin', function(){
     $scope.status.loggedIn = true;
     $scope.digest(); 
     alert('loggedIn');
  });
```

or

```
 $scope.$on('loggedin', function(){
     $scope.apply(function(){
         $scope.status.loggedIn = true; 
     });
     alert('loggedIn');
  });
```

**Edit:**

> why isn't it happening automatically ?

The `setTimeout` function runs outside the angular scope, therefore angular has no idea that you might change something.

You could also solve the problem with the @pixelbits solution. The `$timeout` service is just a wrapper around javascript's `setTimeout` witch executes within the angular scope.

Answer (score 0):

http://plnkr.co/edit/o3XtMLpCquHcU2j2z4v9?p=preview

please add $scope.$apply();

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, testfactory) {
  $scope.status = {
    loggedIn: false
  }


  $scope.test = testfactory;
  $scope.$on('loggedin', function()
  {

    $scope.status.loggedIn = true;

    $scope.$apply();

    alert('loggedIn');
  });
});
```

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clearer in my question. $scope.$apply works, but why do I have to do it? I'm modifying the object inside the scope, so shouldn't the $apply be called automatically?

Comment: as pixelbits mention setTimeout is outside angularjs world so you need call $scope.$apply();

Answer (score 0):

Use $timeout instead of setTimeout. $timeout will trigger a $digest cycle, but setTimeout will not:

```
  $timeout(auth,2000);
```

Comment: Check the comment directly above `setTimeout(auth, 2000);`

Comment: Then wrap setTimeout in an $apply block.